# C#/XNA Why can't I add to the Array List?

Tags: c#, arraylist, xna

I'm having some trouble adding objects to an ArrayList. When attempting to add KeyboardController() and GamepadController() to the ArrayList, i'm told that ControllerList is a field, but it is being used as a type. Both of these classes implement the interface IController. Furthermore, I'm being told that both KC() and GC() must have a return type. Would anyone be able to let me know what is causing the problem. Is there a more proper way of doing this?

```
// Initialization

ArrayList ControllerList;
ControllerList.Add(new KeyboardController());  //error
ControllerList.Add(new GamepadController());   //error

IAnimatedSprite MarioSprite = new SmallMarioRunningRightSprite();

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    foreach(IController Controller in ControllerList)
    {
        Controller.Update();
    }

    MarioSprite.Update();

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

This specific section of code was provided to me by an instructor and I am unclear to why it isn't functioning properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to execute non-initializer code (the calls to `ArrayList.Add`) outside of a method body. This won't work.

You have to either use the collection initializer syntax

```
ArrayList ControllerList = new ArrayList
                               {
                                   new KeyboardController(),
                                   new GamepadController()
                               };
```

or do the initialization in the constructor of your class.

Also, don't use `ArrayList` if you don't have to. Use `List<IController>` instead.

Comment: I've read that List is used in favor of ArrayList, but I kept it because it was instructor given code. Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the item adding code lines in a class constructor or a method.

```
ControllerList = new ArrayList(); 
ControllerList.Add(new KeyboardController());
```

and also you can't add items to not initialized (`null`) ArrayList , you only declare `ControllerList` as `ArrayList` but not initialized

Comment: The OP has a *compilation* error which this answer does nothing to address. It would be appropriate if the error were a NullReferenceException, but isn't appropriate to the currently reported error.